# phpMyAdmin 4.3 Red Dot before SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]I'm an analyst, not a DBA, and have just been upgraded from 2.9 to 4.3 phpMyAdmin on mysql. Now and then when I type a select statement a red dot appears before `SELECT`. When I cursor over it, it says `\u200b`.

Does any one know what this means?

Comment: Could you upload it a picture and post here the url?

Comment: @barbarity picture added

Comment: I'm clueless. I'm also running PHPMyAdmin 4.3.11 and I've never seen anything like that. My only guess is you have a syntax error in that query or he's able to know that the table `CUSTOMERSHIPMENTS` doesn't exist...

Comment: `\u200b` is maybe a Unicode character as it shown like a red dot.

Comment: @shA.t Thanks - that's a possibility, though I haven't been able to reproduce. I'll update if I see this again and can pinpoint the cause.

Comment: @barbarity I do know the table name is valid. If I can figure out the cause, I'll update this question.

Answer (score 0):

`\u200b` is (Zero width space) character.

sometimes it come with your `copy` and usually from text of sites.

Comment: I'm just copying over from .txt. I've tried copying an additional space before SELECT and can't repeat. I'll update when I see again. Thanks.